# TOR Bridge on RaspberryPi with IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: linux, bridge, ipv6

I created a Tor Bridge in my RPi and forwarded the Ports to it as required.
The connections are working fine but only with IPv4.
In the nyx log I can see that it tries to discover the IPv6 but comes up with a "wrong" one.
My router shows a different public IPv6 for this device and nyx comes up with an error trying to connect to the "wrong" one.
How can I enter the correct IPv6 in my brdige configuration?

in torrc i have this:

```
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 [::]:<port>
```

Auto-discovered IPv6 address [xx:xx]:xx has not been found reachable.

Comment: experienced same with default config from https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/guard/debian-ubuntu/ , anyone?